# In Brightcove, can I retrieve a video's thumbnail WITHOUT a media API token?

Tags: brightcove

I would like to use Javascript to retrieve thumbnail URLs from Brightcove-hosted videos.

I can't see a way to do that without exposing my Media API token to the client browser.  ([The with-token method is documented here.](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/samples/find_videos_by_ids.html))

I don't need a token to show the whole video, so it seems insane and unnecessary that I need a token to get the thumbnail url, which obviously I would want to show to the user anyway.

The only workaround I can devise is to create a middleman interface on the server.  (The client JS makes a request to my server, which uses the token to request the thumbnail from BC, then returns it back to the JS.)  That's just annoying.

Am I missing something?  Is there an alternate way to retrieve video thumbnails in the client without exposing the Media API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Brightcove's support, they tell me that the answer is "NO".

They do recommend a server-side relay, which is what I ended up writing, and it works fine.

Disappointing, though.